# How does Apple count app downloads?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

If a user downloads a game but then deletes it, does it still count as a download?
Will if affect the ranking of your app?

Comment: Apple doesn't know when you delete things. They can't "take back the download count"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the app is deleted after being downloaded, it still counts as a download. Deleting the app does not affect the ranking of the app.

If you download the app over and over again using the same Apple ID, it will still count as **one** download. You cannot improve your rating by downloading the same app over and over again unless you use different Apple IDs.

Comment: Added the Apple ID information.